# Engine failure due to turbocharger replaced

Tags: seized-engine

My logan car has a faulty turbocharger when i was go to repair engine that time engine sound was a smooth but when mecanic  replace turbocharger with fitting chines turbo cor then after few km engine run with abnormal sound  . Mecanic then remove oil span he saw no3 big end bearing worn out why these happen please give me a factory manual of logan dls1.5

Comment: I appreciate English may not be your first language but please rewrite your question with some proper spelling and words that make sense. What on earth does 'with fitting chines turbo cor' mean?

Comment: Turbo AND bearings : probably due to poor oil , not changed often, too low and blocked filter...

Comment: Probably just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Turbocharger bearings are very sensitive to poor lubrication.  Engine journal bearings are similar in that they are journal bearings, but they are much more robust in that there is splash oiling, in addition to pumped oil.

Given your description, I would expect that the car was run on low oil which caused lubrication starvation of the turbo.  Usually that failure is very evident, and because it may mess up the mixture and fueling, it gets attention right away.

The number three crank bearing is a little more robust and will still function even after gross lubrication starvation.  One reason for this is that the bearing does not have the rotational speed that the turbocharger bearing has.

My most likely estimate of what happened is that the engine had oil starvation, probably on several occurences. This frequently happens when the engine burns or leaks a little oil, and due to inattention, and then operation with low oil.

Dirty oil over a long time could also cause similar symptoms, however most frequently failures of the turbo and the main bearings is associated with under-lubrication or operation for a period of time with no lubrication.

Comment: As I mentioned above - any thoughts about the filter?

Comment: I discount the filter, as filters have bypasses, both internal to the filter, and on the block.  I have seen several cars with similar symptoms, and in the end, it appears (or the owner confessed) that it was run with no oil (forgot to fill after a change) or low oil (put off checking with an engine which consumed some oil). In the end, we are really looking at most probable cause, because without more detailed history, we will not know many relevant details.